# Deep Water GPU Benchmarks

Tags: h2o

Has anyone run benchmarks of Deep Water and Driverless AI on various video cards? Will a TitanX offer real-world benefit on these tools?

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any formal benchmarks. Deepwater uses TensorFlow and MXNet as deep learning engines, and there are benchmarks for those. In general you'll see significant speed-ups when convolution is involved.

The newer Nvidia cards are faster than old ones (no surprise there), and in particular they have more internal RAM, which determines how large mini-batches you can use for different problems, and how large problems you can work onsome . For example 1080 Ti has 11 GB of RAM while the older 1080 has 8 GB.

Titan X has 12 GB of RAM. It will give you significant speed-ups. However, it's more expensive than 1080 Ti, which is a much better value with almost as much memory.

Szilard Pafka has done benchmarks with different GPU cards. See https://github.com/szilard/benchm-dl